# Node js REST APIs

Tags: node.js

a.  Suppose you are developing a backend-server application for a platform, where you need to trigger a background-job everytime a REST API endpoint is triggered.

What are some ways in which we can:

i.  Ensure that the REST API call doesn’t time-out in case the background job takes more than anticipated time to complete?

ii. Ensure that the background job’s result is correctly communicated to the

API client, in case there is a time-out or connection with the API client is broken?

Comment: I think you should use i. bullmq (https://docs.bullmq.io/) for background process and ii. socket.io (https://socket.io/) for  communicate to client when job is done